# HTML and Javascript "Hamburger Menu" does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, hamburger-menu

I want to use a .js script in my html file, but unfortunately my script does not work the right way :(. I build a responsive Navbar for my website with a "hamburger Menu" on small screensizes.
I managed it to show the "Hamburger Menu" on a smaller screensize but my navbarlinks don't show up if I click on it. Here my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", "initial-scale=1">


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="script/script.js"></script>

 <title>Title</title>

</head> 

<header>
 <nav class="navbar">
   <div class="branding">
     <a href="index.html"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="Brand"></a>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
     <span class="bar"></span>
     <span class="bar"></span>
     <span class="bar"></span>
   </a>
   <div class="navbar-links">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="artikel.html">Artikel</a></li>
       <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
       <li><a href="handel.html">handel</a></li>
       <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
</header>


</body>

</html>
```

here my css:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header{
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: black 3px solid;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}

.branding{
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links{
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

.navbar-links ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links ul li a{
  padding: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar-links a:hover{
  color: #ffbf00;
}

.toggle-button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar{
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1050px) {
  .toggle-button{
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar-links{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-links ul{
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar-links li{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-links li a{
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }

  .navbar-links.active{
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

and the important part I guess, my javascript:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleButton')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Sry for the lot of code, but I want to find the mistake with your help so I post all of my code. Thanks

Comment: Should be `document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')`

Answer (score 0):

it will be `toggle-button` not `toggleButton` in

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0];
```

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0];
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0];
console.log(toggleButton);
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header{
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: black 3px solid;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar{
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}

.branding{
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links{
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

.navbar-links ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links ul li a{
  padding: 25px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar-links a:hover{
  color: #ffbf00;
}

.toggle-button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar{
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1050px) {
  .toggle-button{
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar-links{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-links ul{
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar-links li{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-links li a{
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }

  .navbar-links.active{
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", "initial-scale=1">


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="script/script.js"></script>

 <title>Title</title>

</head> 

<header>
 <nav class="navbar">
   <div class="branding">
     <a href="index.html"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="Brand"></a>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
     <span class="bar"></span>
     <span class="bar"></span>
     <span class="bar"></span>
   </a>
   <div class="navbar-links">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="artikel.html">Artikel</a></li>
       <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
       <li><a href="handel.html">handel</a></li>
       <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you. 
But for some reason it does not work in my browser (no matter which one I use). If I run it here with the "run code snippet" button it works in the way I want. Any ideas why this does not work in my browser?

Comment: @MaximilianMüller it will be `toggle-button`, not `toggleButton`, do you update?

Comment: yes sure I update. I got this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
at script.js:4"